# How msbuild decides which configuration to use if specified configuration is missing?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, csproj

I have 2 projects, first project (MyProject.Web) references second. First project has multiple configurations, while second project has only Debug and Release.

1. MyProject.Web.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;DEV1;DEV2;QA;QA_AUTO</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyProject.Services\MyProject.Services.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

2. MyProject.Services.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

I run msbuild with the following parameters to build first project:

msbuild /p:Configuration=DEV1

How msbuild decides which configuration from second project to use?
What configuration will be selected if I run it with /p:Configuration=UNKNOWN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When specifying a property on the `msbuild` / `dotnet build` command line (`-property:Foo=Bar` or short forms), they are trated as [global property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-properties?view=vs-2019#global-properties) and thus apply to all projects involved in the build.

This means that in your example, all projects will build with `DEV1` set as configuration. Do note that the `Configurations` property is merely a hint to IDEs / Tooling on what strings to offer a user.

If you need to reference a specific configuration, you could update the project reference based on the current configuration:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\TestClassLib\TestClassLib.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug'">
  <!-- Other configurations reference release version -->
  <ProjectReference Update="..\TestClassLib\TestClassLib.csproj" AdditionalProperties="Configuration=Release" />
</ItemGroup>
```